# llama-cpp-python Log printing on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, large-language-model, inference, llama-cpp-python, llamacpp

I use **llama-cpp-python** to run LLMs locally on **Ubuntu**. While generating responses it prints its logs.

How to stop printing of logs??

I found a way to stop log printing for llama.cpp but not for llama-cpp-python. I just want to print the generated response.

Comment: this worked for me: https://github.com/abetlen/llama-cpp-python/issues/478#issuecomment-1652472173